# Jekyll: index.md distorts _includes html of Plotly interactive plot

Tags: html, plotly, jekyll, github-pages

I am using Github Pages and Jekyll to serve Plotly interactive plots. At the moment, for each of the plots, I have Plotly generate the html and save it to `_includes` in my root directory. To display the plots, I've modified the `home.html` layout in `_layouts` to consist of only `{% include filename.html %}` statements and `index.md` to be blank. This does what I want it to do (see image 1) but is somewhat clunky.

[image: Properly displayed page.]

So, I've been trying to modify `home.html` with `<head>` and `<title>` and `<body>` sections, and then placing my `{% include filename.html %}` statements into the body of `index.md`. However, when `home.html` fills `{{ content }}` from `index.md` my plots all of a sudden become compressed in size (see image 2).

[image: Distorted page.]

Is there some way to have the contents from `{% include filename.html %}` statements fill the whole page, as was the case when I had `{% include filename.html %}` statements in `home.html`?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: the issue seems to be with the Plotly figure itself rather than with Jekyll. Adding `autosize=False`, `height=700`, and `width=1400` to `update_layout` fixes the compression issue noted above. Of course, it'd be nice to avoid this kind of hard-coding. See also: https://community.plotly.com/t/plot-sizing-problems/1620/27.